# Pyglet/Cocos2d, window appears but sprite doesn't spawn

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to create a sprite class and a key handle to move the sprite, but it doesn't seem to be working. When executed the window will appear, but sprite doesn't. What's wrong with it?

```
import pyglet
import cocos
from pyglet.window import key

window = pyglet.window.Window()
keyboard = key.KeyStateHandler()

class Player(cocos.layer.Layer):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Player, self).__init__()

    img = pyglet.image.load('../game/resources/sprite_1.png')
    self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img)

  def animate(dt, velocity, sprite):
    sprite.position += dt * velocity

  def on_key_press(self, symbol, keyboard, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.RIGHT:
        self.img.x += dt * 10
    elif symbol == key.LEFT:
        self.img.x -= dt * 10
    elif symbol == key.UP:
        self.img.y += dt * 10
    elif symbol == key.DOWN:
        self.img.y -= dt * 10



  def on_key_release(self, smybol, keyboard, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.RIGHT:
        self.sprite.x = dt * 0
    elif symbol == key.LEFT:
        self.sprite.x = dt * 0
    elif symbol == key.DOWN:
        self.sprite.y = dt * 0
    elif symbol == key.UP:
        self.sprite.y = dt * 0


pyglet.gl.glEnable(pyglet.gl.GL_BLEND)
pyglet.gl.glBlendFunc(pyglet.gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, pyglet.gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems in your code which are preventing anything from happening:

1. You're creating a cocos2d entity within pyglet, without telling pyglet how to handle it. You're possibly better off using cocos2d for things like window creation etc.
2. You're creating a pyglet `Sprite` when you should probably be using a cocos2d one, and you're not attaching it to the `Layer`.
3. `animate` isn't part of the API for `Layer` (and even if it was, it would probably not be a static method).
4. You haven't defined `Player` as an event handler, so `on_key_press` etc won't do anything.
5. You're passing more arguments into `on_key_press` etc than are required, and are referencing `dt` without passing it in.

Here is a modified version of your sample code which should help you move forward:

```
import cocos
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

keyboard = key.KeyStateHandler()

class Player(cocos.layer.Layer):
    is_event_handler = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        img = pyglet.image.load('../game/resources/sprite_1.png')
        self.sprite = cocos.sprite.Sprite(img)
        self.add(self.sprite)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        print 'pressing'
        if symbol == key.RIGHT:
            self.sprite.x += 10
        elif symbol == key.LEFT:
            self.sprite.x -= 10
        elif symbol == key.UP:
            self.sprite.y += 10
        elif symbol == key.DOWN:
            self.sprite.y -= 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cocos.director.director.init()

    player = Player()
    main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene( player )

    cocos.director.director.run( main_scene )
```